# WORK LOST!!!!!!! SUPER URGENT!

Tags: texstudio, editors

please I need your help. I have to send tomorrow my master thesis. I had it almost finished when all my code has changed.

I have extracted the pdf and when I have tried to save my code it was substituted by:

```
%%
%% This is file `pdfx.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% pdfx.dtx  (with options: `package')
%% 
%%  Copyright (c) 2019, CV Radhakrishnan <cvr@river-valley.org>,
%%    Han The Thanh <thanh@river-valley.org>,
%%    Ross Moore <ross.moore@mq.edu.au>,
%%    Peter Selinger <selinger@mathstat.dal.ca>
%% 
%%  This file may be distributed and/or modified under the conditions
%%  of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.2 of this
%%  license or (at your option) any later version.  The latest version
%%  of this license is in:
%% 
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% 
%%  and version 1.2 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%%  version 1999/12/01 or later.
```

I think it has created a sty file from my pdf. But I still need to work with my original code. Did I lose it? Please, I need a solution!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It's post probably an editor problem. Which is it?

Comment: look into your working direktory. There ahould be at least a backup  file of your tex document.

Comment: this is unrelated to pdftex it might be related to the editor you are using (you have not said which that is)  what you show is not generated by any code it is a copy of the pdfx package, which is normally at a location such as `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdfx/pdfx.sty` so the question (which only you can answer) is why is that file opened in your editor rather than your document.

Comment: I do not know. Actually, my tex document is this now. I use LatexStudio.

Comment: latexstudio? I have not heard of that? texstudio? anyway if you look in a filemanager at your working directory do you see your file (or a backup copy)

Comment: Sorry, TexStudio

Comment: No. I see the same as before but my tex file has changed the code.

Comment: then you will need to restore from a backup (that hopefully you have) it is hard to see how you could accidentally copy pdfx.sty over your document and save it without warning but clearly any editor would have that ability.

Comment: I neither how I did it... I have read that there is a package sty2dtx that can change from sty to dtx. Do you know anything about it?

Comment: no but it can not help recover your original document. The file you show is just a copy of a package in the standard tex distribution, it has no information that would allow any tool to recover your text. You need to find a backup or get at least the text from your pdf and re-add the tex markup.

Comment: and is it possible to restore windows to the moment I meshed it up or some point before?

Comment: I'm not sure windows restore points account for personal data. I guess it depends whether your computer has one or more partitions / hard drives (C, D, etc)... Also you'd need a restore point where your thesis is there, fine and not in its early stages. I guess hold on to that PDF as reworking it to tex markup is likely the way to go...

Comment: I should warn you that Norton does not back up .tex files unless you specifically add the extension to the list.  (I learned that the hard way.)